# Quickest way to obtain data when comparing two tables and one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the quickest way between JOINS, INTERCEPT (or EXCEPT) or NOT EXISTS
if I want to know the list of emails of Table A that don't appear in Table B.

In table A I have 10 million distinct emails and 46 million tables in Table B.

I need to find out emails that are in Table A but not in Table B

Ex 1 with EXCEPT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.email
FROM database.tablea a
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT b.email 
FROM database.tableb b
```

Ex 2 with LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.email
FROM database.tablea a
LEFT OUTER JOIN database.tableb b
ON a.email=b.email
```

Ex 3 with NOT EXISTS

```
not sure how to write this one...
```

Comment: Are the emails unique in `tablea`?  `SELECT DISTINCT` is expensive.

Comment: no its a login table so an email can appear as many times as a user logs in

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to write:

```
select distinct email
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.email = a.email);
```

For performance, this really wants indexes on `a(email)` and `b(email)`.